# Angularjs - user input in controller

Tags: angularjs, http, angularjs-scope

I want to use a user input value in to controller. for example i want to take a URL and send a HTTP GET request. I have tried the following format , unfortunatly it does not work.

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl' , function($scope, $http){
$http.get("{{url}}")
.success(function(response){
$scope.data=response.data;
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the `url` retrieved from a user's input

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.callAPI = function() {
    console.log($scope.url);
    $http.get($scope.url)
      .success(function(response) {
        $scope.result = response.data;
      });
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Enter url :
  <input type="text" ng-model="url" />
  <input type="submit" ng-click="callAPI()" />
  
  <div ng-bind="result"></div>
</div>
```

***Note*** : This will show an error if you entered a wrong url

Comment: No problem mate, don't forget to mark it as the answer if it helped you